# Differential word problem

Tags: calculus

For whatever reason I am incapable of doing this problem.

The circumference of a sphere was measured to be 84 cm with a possible error of .5 cm
a) use differentials to estimate the max error in calculated surface area. What is the relative error?

I know that the formula will be $A=4 \pi r^2$ and that the radius is $r= \frac{84}{2\pi}$

know that I will find the error by using differentials where I get

$\frac {dx}{dy} = f \prime (x)$

$ dy = dx f \prime (x)$

$dy=.05 (8\pi r)$   is the same as   $dy = .5 (8\pi\frac{84}{2\pi})$

which is the wrong answer. I have no idea what I am doing wrong besides that I suck at math.

Comment: You want $\Delta A = \frac {dA}{dc}\Delta c$ where $c$ is the circumference.  I don't know what $f$, $x$ and $y$ are

Comment: f is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .05 is wrong, but the final answer you get looks OK to me (for the maximum error; for the relative error, it seems to me we did a problem of that sort very recently, you could go look for it). Why do you say it's wrong?

EDIT: I think I made the same mistake you made. $.5$ is the possible error in the *circumference* but you've put it into your answer where you need the possible error in the *radius*. Since $C=2\pi r$, $dC=2\pi dr$, so $dr=dC/(2\pi)=(.5)/(2\pi)$. Put that number for what you are calling $dx$, and you should be OK.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{84}{\pi}$ and I can't get that.

Comment: Ahhh I get it now, I can't believe I spent so long on this problem and I couldn't get it. I don't know why I have such a problem with math like this.